# RuntimeError : Memory Access Out of Bounds - WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error, unity-webgl

when I'm creating WebGL built using WebGL Publisher form Asset store I'm not getting this error but when I'm trying to create the WebGL built using File tab (Built Settings or Built And Run) i.e. Ctrl+B or Ctrl+Shift+B then It's generating error "exception thrown: RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds,RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds".
I'm using .jslib plugins to access cookies from browser in Unity
libraries I'm using are NuGet, Newtonsoft.JSON, WebSocketSharp-netstandard, Proyecto26.RestClient, RSG.Promise.

I've tried

1. narrowing code by removing plugins
2. updating unity versions from 2020.3 to 2022.3
3. tested the codebase for any memory related issues
4. testing on different browsers

I've expected to either get the solution or get aware of what is causing this error.

Comment: Sounds like your app is exceeding one of the WebGL specific memory limits - https://blog.unity.com/engine-platform/understanding-memory-in-unity-webgl